# Multidimension Array PHP + issue on how to create it

Tags: php, arrays

I want the following array :

```
$array = array(
'test1' => array(
    'cat1' => 'val1',
    'cat2' => 'val2',
    'cat3' => 'val3'
    ),
'test2' => array(
    'cat1' => 'val1',
    'cat2' => 'val2',
    'cat3' => 'val3'
    )
);
```

But I need to create it in 2 times.

First, I create the first dimension :

```
$array[] = 'test1';
$array[] = 'test2';
```

And then I don't know how to add an array to each element ('test1', 'test2) to get the result like above.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `$array['test']['anykey']= "some value here"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this ?

```
<?php
$array = array(
'test1' => array(
    'cat1' => 'val1',
    'cat2' => 'val2',
    'cat3' => 'val3'
    ),
'test2' => array(
    'cat1' => 'val1',
    'cat2' => 'val2',
    'cat3' => 'val3'
    )
);

foreach($array as $k=>$arr)
{
$new_arr[$k]=$arr;
}

print_r($new_arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [test1] => Array
        (
            [cat1] => val1
            [cat2] => val2
            [cat3] => val3
        )

    [test2] => Array
        (
            [cat1] => val1
            [cat2] => val2
            [cat3] => val3
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Jutr try with:

```
$array['test1'] = array();
$array['test2'] = array();
```